# Toggle menu/accordion menu doesn't work?

Tags: magento-1.7, menu

I have been trying to add accordion menu on the left side bar on our new magento ecommerce site. I tried most of the methods mentioned on Magento website forums but nothing seems to work. I even tried the plugin called Codewix for accordion menu plugin, it did not work and even crashed my whole site.

I also tried various scriptalicious accordions and they all had issues. I want to do it in jQuery since I had enough with all the other ones. Can I know which js file is save to remove from Magento front end, I do not want to mess up big time.

It would be highly appreciated if you could share any method for accordion menu that works for you in 1.7.0.2 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses another JavaScript library called Prototype which will conflict with jQuery unless jQuery is set into no-conflict mode http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

If you don't want to refactor the jQuery code to use another selector, here's some workarounds and hints: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/