# jQuery conflict - newbie

Tags: javascript

Installed a search extension and now the shopping cart is broken.  Am getting a javascript error.

When the extension is disabled everything works fine. The Extension support told me to empty their .js file. But that does not fix the issue.

I don't understand where the $.noConflict(); should go.

Comment: This should help: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: No it is not, the question is: Where should I put the jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Good question. I didn't even know of noConflict. I rewrote some jQuery code to use `jQuery` instead of `$` to get around the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic, but it's a duplicate of a common question

Comment: What's wrong with Anton S's answer, by the way?

Answer (score 3):

open up your included jQuery file and add to the last line. You can see from view-source from where it is included:

```
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

or just

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: OK - so I added jQuery.noConflict(); to the last line of the jquery.min.js file included in the extension and it did nothing to help. Other ideas?  The extension is Sphinx Search  @anton

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is conflicting with Magento's out of the box javascript library, Prototype.

See question:
[Toggle menu/accordion menu doesn't work?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4970/toggle-menu-accordion-menu-doesnt-work/6680#6680)

You can wrap the javascript code from the extension in an anonymous no-conflict wrapper eg:

```
(function ($) {

....
(extension code here)
....

})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

The main issue that arises between jQuery and Prototype is contention for the $ operator, which jQuery uses as a short form for the jQuery function.  You should be able to get an idea of the code that is conflicting from the javascript error message.

Comment: An answer which is a link to another answer which is basically two links. Care to elaborate? Include some content please.

Comment: @philwinkle The links in the other answer (which is to a question which is a duplicate of this one) are to canonical jQuery resources and answer the question.  No point in cut and pasting content from either in to this answer.  Feel free to a) Edit my answer, b) add an answer of your own, or c) down vote the answer if it's that bad.

Comment: just pitching in to help keep the community clean. Nothing personal mate. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers

Comment: @roscius I had already seen that post and the links - but that still did not answer my question.

Comment: @Wesley I've added some more info, if you're still having the problem, it would be helpful for you to post the error message you are receiving in to your question.

Comment: @philwinkle Nothing personal here either mate, would be good to hear your perspective on the question.  Fair dinkum.